# Where's the radio?

Tags: audio

I want to replace the radio on my Renault Grand Espace series 3 (T reg.) but can't find where all the wires go to. They must all end up in a central place, surely? Once found, I can extend them to where I want the replacement to go. But where are they?

Comment: Several Renaults of that era deliberately put different parts of the radio in different parts of the car.  This was to deter theft as you couldn't just lift one box and run off.  So, "They must all end up in a central place" - not necessarily.

Comment: @Chenmunka - fair comment. I need basically to find the speaker terminals, which I'd have thought would all be together, and the plug end of the aerial, which may well be elsewhere! Power's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the model where there is no distinct stereo unit in the dash itself, the actual head unit is in the boot so that would be where the speaker and antenna wires would be.

Comment: It's an Espace - there isn't a boot per se! The CD changer is there, in a back corner. The aerial is over the front windscreen, so I doubt the wire would go to the back of the vehicle.

Comment: @Tim that’s an interesting assumption - there are many cars with rear mounted aerials that go all the way to the front...